# TensorFlow: lack of repeatability in tf.estimator.DNNClassifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, random-seed

I wish to use TensorFlow to perform classification on medical datasets.
To do this, I am using exactly the same code as that proposed in https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/estimator, the only difference being that I face medical datasets rather than the Iris database. So, it is not custom code.

I do need help about the following problem: if I run the same code on the same data with the same parameters for the network configuration (number of layers, number of neurons in each layer, and so on) , the results are different. I mean, I run the same code ten times, and I obtain ten different values for the accuracy. These values are even largely different, as they range from 73% up to 83%.

This means that the subjects considered suffering from a given disease vary from a run to another. Differently said, once set a network structure, there are several subjects who are considered either healthy or sick depending on the run only.

As you can imagine, this lack of repeatability makes that code useless from both scientific and medical viewpoints: another user, running the same configuration over the same data set, would find a different model and different results, so would cure different subjects.

I have noticed that for the Iris database the problem seems not to take place, and accuracy is always 0.9666. This depends on the problem being very easy (linearly separable for all but one items, and very small data set).

I have carried out a search on the internet, and I have found several other people who have noted the same problem. As for the possible solutions, I have read several as well, I have implemented them all, with no result.

Here I add a short list of some suggested remedies that failed in my case:

```
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'

np.random.seed(0)

tf.set_random_seed(0)

rn.seed(0)

tf.reset_default_graph()

session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
    intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
    inter_op_parallelism_threads=1
)

sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
```

Is there any chance to fix this problem? It is a pity that such an excellent tool, as TensorFlow is, cannot guarantee repeatibility.

I am using the following:

custom code: no, it is the one in https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/estimator

system: Apple

OS: Mac OsX 10.13

TensorFlow version: 1.3.0

Python version: 3.6.3

GPU model: AMD FirePro D700 (actually, two such GPUs)

Thank you very much!

Best regards

Ivanoe De Falco